# Map destructor error

Tags: c++, dictionary, destructor

I am writing a c++ app to implement this:

Given an arbitrary text document written in English, write a program that will generate a
concordance, i.e. an alphabetical list of all word occurrences, labeled with word frequencies.
Bonus: label each word with the sentence numbers in which each occurrence appeared.

But every time it just end with core dump, I saw the stack trace, it is some error of calling free(). I have read my code for many times, can't find the error. Could anyone help?

Thanks

The input : doc.txt

```
Given an arbitrary text document written in English, write a program that will generate a
concordance, i.e. an alphabetical list of all word occurrences, labeled with word frequencies.
Bonus: label each word with the sentence numbers in which each occurrence appeared.
```

DocParser.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <ext/hash_map>
#include <ext/hash_set>

namespace std { using namespace __gnu_cxx; }

using namespace std;

struct ltstr
{
  bool operator()(char* s1, char* s2) const
  {
    return strcmp(s1, s2) < 0;
  }
};


class DocParser {
public:
  DocParser (const char* file, const hash_set<char>& lineSeparators);
  ~DocParser ();
  void Parse ();
  void PrintResult ();
private:
  struct Record {
    int numOccurance;
    vector<int> sentences;
    Record (int num, int sentenceId) {
      numOccurance = num;
      sentences.push_back(sentenceId);
    }
  };
  //typedef hash_map<char*, Record*, hash<char*>, ltstr> Map;
  typedef map<char*, Record*, ltstr> Map;
  ifstream inFile;
  Map wordMap;
  hash_set<char> lineSeparators;
  void Increment(char* word, int sentenceId);
};
```

DocParser.cpp:

```
#include "DocParser.h"

DocParser::DocParser (const char* fileName, const hash_set<char>& lineSeparators) 
    : inFile (fileName), lineSeparators (lineSeparators) {
}

DocParser::~DocParser () { 
  if (inFile.is_open()) {
    inFile.close();
  }

  Map::iterator it;
  for ( it = wordMap.begin(); it != wordMap.end(); it++ ) {
    delete (char*)it->first;
    delete (Record*)it->second;
  }
}

bool IsAB (char c) {
  if ( c <= 'z' && c >= 'a' || c <= 'Z' && c>='A')
    return true;
  return false;
}

bool InWord (char* buf, int wordBegin, int currentIndex) {
  bool ret;
  if ( IsAB(buf[currentIndex]) )
    ret = true;
  else {
    if ( wordBegin > 0 && buf[currentIndex] == '.' &&
        (currentIndex - 1 == wordBegin || buf[currentIndex - 2] == '.') ) {
      ret = true;
    } else {
      ret = false;
    }
  }
  return ret;
} 

void DocParser::Parse () { 
  char buf[1024]; 
  int sentenceId = 1;

  while (!inFile.eof()) {
    inFile.getline(buf, sizeof(buf));
    cout << buf << endl;

    int wordBegin = -1;
    int len = strlen(buf);
    int index = 0;
    while (index < len) {
      if ( InWord(buf, wordBegin, index) ) {
         if (wordBegin == -1) wordBegin = index;
      } else {
         char currentChar = buf[index];
         if (wordBegin != -1) {
           buf[index] = 0;
           Increment(&buf[wordBegin], sentenceId);
           wordBegin = -1;
         }
         if ( lineSeparators.find(currentChar) != lineSeparators.end() ) {
           sentenceId++;
         }
      }
      index++;
    }
    if (wordBegin != -1) {
      Increment(&buf[wordBegin], sentenceId);
    }
  }
}

void DocParser::Increment (char* key, int sentenceId) {
  Map::iterator it = wordMap.find(key);

  if (it == wordMap.end()) {
    char* buf = new char[ strlen(key) ];
    strcpy(buf, key);
    wordMap[buf] = new Record(1, sentenceId);
  } else {
    it->second->numOccurance++;
    it->second->sentences.push_back(sentenceId);
  }
}

void DocParser::PrintResult () {
  Map::iterator it;
  for ( it = wordMap.begin(); it != wordMap.end(); it++ ) {
    cout << it->first << "\t\t" ;
    cout << "{" << it->second->numOccurance << ":" ;
    cout << it->second->sentences[0] ;
    for (int i = 1; i < it->second->sentences.size(); i++) {
      cout << "," ;
      cout << it->second->sentences[i];
    }
    cout << "}" << "\n";
  }
}
```

Main:

```
#include "DocParser.h"

int main () {
  char separators[] = {'!', '.', '?', };
  hash_set<char> lineSeparators(separators, separators + 3);
  DocParser p("doc.txt", lineSeparators);
  p.Parse();
  p.PrintResult();

}
```

The Error Msg:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x08870868 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0x3f3fb6]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x22)[0x79e3fc2]
./a.out[0x8048ec4]
./a.out[0x804c580]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x39be36]
./a.out[0x8048d51]
======= Memory map: ========
00364000-00381000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 47857      /lib/ld-2.13.so
00381000-00382000 r--p 0001c000 fd:00 47857      /lib/ld-2.13.so
00382000-00383000 rw-p 0001d000 fd:00 47857      /lib/ld-2.13.so
00385000-00508000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 47858      /lib/libc-2.13.so
00508000-00509000 ---p 00183000 fd:00 47858      /lib/libc-2.13.so
00509000-0050b000 r--p 00183000 fd:00 47858      /lib/libc-2.13.so
0050b000-0050c000 rw-p 00185000 fd:00 47858      /lib/libc-2.13.so
0050c000-0050f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00540000-00568000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 72273      /lib/libm-2.13.so
00568000-00569000 r--p 00027000 fd:00 72273      /lib/libm-2.13.so
00569000-0056a000 rw-p 00028000 fd:00 72273      /lib/libm-2.13.so
0065f000-00660000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
006b4000-006d0000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 72267      /lib/libgcc_s-4.5.1-20100924.so.1
006d0000-006d1000 rw-p 0001b000 fd:00 72267      /lib/libgcc_s-4.5.1-20100924.so.1
07936000-07a19000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 72317      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
07a19000-07a1d000 r--p 000e2000 fd:00 72317      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
07a1d000-07a1f000 rw-p 000e6000 fd:00 72317      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
07a1f000-07a25000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
08048000-08051000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 411297     /home/leon/Projects/sem/bridge_water/a.out
08051000-08052000 rw-p 00008000 fd:00 411297     /home/leon/Projects/sem/bridge_water/a.out
0886e000-0888f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b78a5000-b78a8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b78b6000-b78b8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bfe35000-bfe56000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Why all those char *'s? Have you heard of std::string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char* buf = new char[ strlen(key) ];
strcpy(buf, key);
```

You haven't left enough room for the null terminator.

But please use C++ strings.